# ApplicationBar with minimized mode override WebBrowser component at landscape orientation

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, alignment, webbrowser-control, application-bar

[image: Application Bar override web browser]

i have been read some similar questions on Stackoverflow but cannot make it works correctly
Here is my WebBrowser XAML code

```
<phone:WebBrowser Name="webBrowser" 
                  ScriptNotify="webBrowser_ScriptNotify" 
                  IsScriptEnabled="True" 
                  Margin="0" 
                  Background="Transparent"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
```

and Application Bar in code

```
void BuildAppBar()
{
    ApplicationBar = new ApplicationBar();
    ApplicationBar.Mode = ApplicationBarMode.Minimized;
    ...
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when you have set the Mode Property of `ApplicationBar` to `Minimized` (i don't know why), so what you can do is to use `OrientationChanged` event of the page to set the Mode Property:

```
private void PhoneApplicationPage_OrientationChanged(object sender, OrientationChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Orientation == PageOrientation.PortraitUp)
    {
        this.ApplicationBar.Mode = ApplicationBarMode.Minimized;
    }
    else
    {
        this.ApplicationBar.Mode = ApplicationBarMode.Default;
    }
}
```